# Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, mysql

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\reporting\download.php on line 136
```

Line 136 is `$filename=strtoupper($_SESSION["SystemNameStr"])'_LOGINHISTORY_'.date('Ymd').'.CSV';`

```
if ($numlog>=1)
    {
    $filename=strtoupper($_SESSION["SystemNameStr"])'_LOGINHISTORY_'.date('Ymd').'.CSV';
    header("Pragma: public");  // Added to allow IE to download through SSL tunnels.
    header("Cache-Control: private");
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename ");
```

Comment: The end of the strtoupper() call followed by '_LONGHISTORY_' doesn't look right

Answer (score 2):

Try with a "." after the strtoupper function.

```
$filename=strtoupper($_SESSION["SystemNameStr"]).'LOGINHISTORY'.date('Ymd').'.CSV';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$filename=strtoupper($_SESSION["SystemNameStr"])'_LOGINHISTORY_'.date('Ymd').'.CSV';`

You aren't concatenating as you think you are... Use:

`$filename=strtoupper($_SESSION["SystemNameStr"]).'_LOGINHISTORY_'.date('Ymd').'.CSV';`